# Using WSGI with a specific python binary

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Can wsgi be configured to use a *specific* python executable?

When using the WSGIPythonHome directive, you supply a prefix. What does mod_wsgi look for in that directory? I assume it looks in the supplied directory for the executable ../bin/python . If the executable is called, say, python26, will it be found? I assume not.

(Details: The system python on the server I'm using is 2.4 and I'm trying to upgrade. I don't have sudo on the machine, and I'm trying to work with my admin on this... I'm not sure why we can't just install the new version of python in /opt or /usr/local with the standard directory structure, so we can use WSGIPythonHome in the normal way, which is what I would do. I'm just trying to work with him and be agreeable.)

---

Alternatively, does mod_wsgi just use the python binary it was compiled against? So if we recompile mod_wsgi with the new version of python, will it always use that one?

Comment: your sysadmin might not know that you can do "make altinstall" when building python and it will automatically go in /usr/local with a specific name (like python2.7).

Comment: @andrewcooke actually that's exactly what he did. It turns out that the python26 install came with it's own, separate mod_wsgi, so presumable we can load that wsgi module instead and we'll be all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must recompile mod_wsgi from source code against version/installation of Python you wish to use. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Multiple_Python_Versions

and:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Unable_To_Find_Python_Shared_Library

Comment: Yes, I know that I need to recompile mod_wsgi with the new version. My question is: is that sufficient? Will mod_wsgi *use* the installation it was compiled against, or the one in the system PATH? Would I need to use the WSGPythonHome directive *in addition to* recompiling mod_wsgi?

Comment: The documentation explains that. I have also added reference to additional section in that document where it talks about possibility where library not in standard location. In that case need to set an environment variable when building mod_wsgi to make sure it looks in right spot.